# Kinect Cursor Control with virtual XNA-Rectangle-'Touchpad' - Y-Axis inverted

Tags: c#, xna, kinect, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to implement a Real-Time Strategy control scheme for the MS Kinect.
So far, I've got a cursor, which can be moved by moving your left Hand (or right, dependant on your handedness). I've got an Open-NI-based Kinect controller which sets up a skeleton for player-movements and delivers the wrist-, elbow-, shoulder- and body-center-coordinates to my application.
To project these wrist-coordinates to the screen, I've set up a Rectangle, which is situated slightly left/right from the player's center and as long as the wrist moves inside the rectangle, the cursor moves on screen.
My problem is, that the XNA-Rectangle has the upper left corner as point of origin, i.e. the X-axis points right, as it "should", but the Y-axis points down, while the Y-axis of the Kinect - coordinate system points up. This results in the cursor moving upwards on screen, when I move my hand down and vice versa. There's no way for me to change anything with the Kinect-coordinate system, so is it possible to 'flip' the 'coordinate system' of the rectangle, so that it's Y-axis points up,too?

Here's the relevant code:

(from Calibrate()-Method:)

```
List<Vector3> joints = UDPlistener.getInstance().ParseCalibCoordinates(data);
//0 = Right Wrist 1 = Right Elbow 2 = Right Shoulder
//3 = Left Wrist  4 = Left Elbow 5 = Left Shoulder
//6 = Center
height = 762; 
width = 1024;            
switch (hand)
{
    case 0:
    cursorSpace = new Rectangle((int)(joints[6].X * 2) - 200, (int)(joints[6].Y * 2) + height, width, height);
    break;
    case 3:
    cursorSpace = new Rectangle((int)(joints[6].X * 2) - 1200, (int)(joints[6].Y * 2) + height, width, height);
    break;
}

public Point Cursor(String data)
{   
    List<Vector3> joints = UDPlistener.getInstance().ParsePlayCoordinates(data);
    //0 = Right Wrist 1 = Left Wrist 2 = Center
    double mhx = 0; //main hand x-coordinate
    double mhy = 0; // main hand y-coordinate
    switch (hand)
    {
        case 0:
        mhx = joints[hand].X;
        mhy = joints[hand].Y;
        break; 

        case 3:
        mhx = joints[hand-2].X;
        mhy = joints[hand-2].Y;
        break;                    
    }

int x; 
int y;
if (Math.Abs(mhx - mhxOld) < 1.0 || Math.Abs(mhy - mhyOld) < 1.0) 
//To remove jittering of the cursor
{
    x = (int) mhxOld * 2;
    y = (int) mhyOld * 2;  
}
else
{
    x = (int) mhx * 2;
    mhxOld = mhx;
    y = (int) mhy * 2;
    mhyOld = mhy;
}

Point cursor = new Point(0,0);

if (cursorSpace.Contains(x,y)) 
{
    cursor = new Point(x - cursorSpace.X, y - CursorSpace.Y);                    
    lastCursorPos = cursor;
    return cursor;                    
}
```

Sorry for the wall of text, I hope, I could make myself clear.

Thanks in advance,

KK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use an extension method for converting OpenNI coordinates. The following example maps the OpenNI coordinates to XNA coordinates in a 640x480 rectangle in the top left corner, represented as a Vector2 object.

```
public static Vector2 ToXnaCoordinates(this Point3D point)
{
    return new Vector2(
        point.X + 320,
        (point.Y - 240) * -1);
}
```

The magic that flips the y coordinate is the `* -1` part.

If you want to reach a rectangle of different size than 640x480, you need to scale the coordinates accordingly after conversion. Example:

```
public static Vector2 ToScaledXnaCoordinates(this Point3D point, int rectSizeX, int rectSizeY)
{
    return new Vector2(
        (point.X + 320) * rectSizeX / 640,
        (point.Y - 240) * -rectSizeY / 480);
}
```

Comment: Ok, it worked, thanks a lot. Another problem arose however. With my approach, I had a neat area which was shifted towards the user's cursor-hand and made each point on screen easily reachable without stretching or bending overmuch. I applied your method in my 'Cursor'-Method's switch(hand)-block, and it works fabulously, but now the 'sensor'-area is exactly in front of the player and goes down to slightly above knee-level. I tried using the unmodified hand coordinates for the 'if (cursorSpace.Contains)' and then apply your 'magic' as offset afterwards,but it didn't work as intended. Any ideas?

Comment: In order to minimize hand movements for maximum reach, I suggest tweaking the +320 and -240. Additionally, you might want to scale your coordinates (after shifting) to the size of the rectangle. Basically, you will have to experiment with changing the +320, -240, 640, 480 values. Unfortunately, I can't provide an ideal solution, since it varies from case to case. Don't forget, however, that accuracy decreases with the increase of the target area size.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't XNA, but I wanted to put this out there for those wpf users:) If you are using something like [Channel 9's](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart/Skeletal-Tracking-Fundamentals) approach, just have a bool to determine if inverted or not. Example:

```
    private void ScalePosition(FrameworkElement element, Joint joint, bool inverted)
    {
        //convert the value to X/Y
        Joint scaledJoint = joint.ScaleTo(967, 611);

        //convert & scale (.3 = means 1/3 of joint distance)
        //Joint scaledJoint = joint.ScaleTo(1280, 720, 1f, 1f);
        if (!inverted)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(element, scaledJoint.Position.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(element, scaledJoint.Position.Y);
        }

        if (inverted)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(element, scaledJoint.Position.X);
            Canvas.SetBottom(element, scaledJoint.Position.Y);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps WPF users!